# Question of Hausdorff measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm self-learning graduate Real Analysis and currently on Hausdorff Measure section.  Can someone help me with this question? Thank you so much.

> Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$. Prove that for any subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, we have for any $\delta \gt 0$
>   $$\mathcal{H}_1^{\delta}(A) = \mathcal{H}_1(A).$$
>   Prove that if $A$ is bounded, then
>   $$\mathcal{H}_1(A) \lt \infty.$$

(The original image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F0iE.png).)

Comment: What does your notation mean? What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: You need to tell us what you mean by $\mathcal{H}_1^\delta$. (I'm guessing that $\mathcal{H}^1$ is the one-dimensional Hausdorff measure (and I can almost guess about $\mathcal{H}_1^\delta$, but I don't want to start typing up an answer just to find out that my guess was wrong...) Exact notation differs from book to book.

Comment: If this means what I think it does (I haven't looked at it in many years), you simply want to make use of the fact that every open interval can be written as a countable union of open intervals each of which has length less than $\delta.$ For the $A$ is bounded question, if you have monotonicity available, just make use of the fact that $A$ is contained in some bounded open interval. Even if you don't know the measure of an open interval is its length, the infimum aspect of the definition along with "open interval" shows that the measure of the open interval is **at most** its length.

Answer (score 1):

The quantity $\mathcal H_1^\delta(A)$ comes from covering $A$ by open intervals of length at most $\delta$, then adding their lengths, and taking infimum. But when we are on the line, the constraint "size less than $\delta$" is easy to get around: take any cover by  open intervals, partition each into pieces of length $<\delta/2$, then expand each piece by $(1+\epsilon)$ to make sure the partition points are also covered. This produces a cover by intervals of size $<\delta$, with sum of length equal to $(1+\epsilon)$ times the original sum. Since $(1+\epsilon)$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$, we conclude that the constraint "size less than $\delta$" has no effect on the infimum of sum of lengths. Simply put, $\mathcal H_1^\delta(A)$ does not depend on $\delta$.

For the second part. If $A\subseteq [-M,M]$, then $H^\delta_1(A)\le 2M$ for $\delta\ge 2M$, just by covering $A$ with a single interval. By the above, $H_1(A)\le 2M$.